# Display animation while on pages and while routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router, transition

I have a React application that displays a loading screen when the user clicks the submit button to wait for a service call PUT to complete. Then, they get routed to the next page. On the next page it displays another loading screen while it waits for the service call GET to complete.

Currently I have a reducer that starts and stops this animation.
The only problem is, it never makes it to the next page because I display the animation component on routing. I need the animation to display while routing.

I have a custom component called Interstitial (my animation component).
How can I display this animation on the home page, through the page routing, to the next page so it looks like one continuous loading screen and not three seperate ones.

```
render() {
    if (isWaiting) {
        return <Interstitial />; //this is my animation
    } else {
        return (
            <Template>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                        <Route path="/verify-changes" component={VerifyChanges} />
                        <Route path="/confirm" component={Confirm} />
                    </Switch>
            </Template>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by adding inside of the return with the switch statement and not as a second return.

```
{this.props.isWaiting ? <Interstitial /> : null}
```